# Young adult/children's fantasy trilogy set in an Oregon forest

Tags: story-identification, books

Searching for a book I heard mentioned in the Stuff You Should Know podcast (How the Grimm Brothers Worked). They didn't enunciate very clearly, so all I could pick up was that it was recent, by an author whose last name was (or sounded like) "Lloyd" (and may be female), it was a series of three books set in an Oregon forest with a fantastical theme which set it apart from other recent books.

Comment: What about the theme was fantastical?

Comment: Don't know—in the podcast it was used as a good example of certain thematic elements from fairy tales still being integrated into modern fiction. Thanks for the answers @Sean Duggan and rand al'thor! I'll take a look when I get home. I'm thinking just from reading the answers that Wildwood is the match, although Griffin's Calling is certainly looking like a great series to read :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Wildwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildwood_(novel))*

> ... is a 2011 children's fantasy novel by The Decemberists' singer-songwriter Colin Meloy, illustrated by his wife Carson Ellis. The 541 page novel, inspired by classic fantasy novels and folk tales, is the story of two seventh-graders who are drawn into a hidden, magical forest, while trying to rescue a baby kidnapped by crows. They get caught up in an epic struggle, and learn of their connection to a magical parallel world while confronting adult authorities who are often cowardly or dishonest. The natural beauty and local color of Portland, Oregon figure prominently in the book."

Recent book, last name sounds kind of like Lloyd and set in an Oregon forest. There's only one book so far, but Meloy plans to write more when he has time away from his band, and the plot is apparently explicitly divided into three parts. With 541 pages, that's pretty close to a compiled trilogy right there.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be [*Griffin's Calling* by N. R. Rose](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Griffin_s_Calling.html?id=OvO6tMDLY6EC&redir_esc=y)?

The description here says:

> When troubled teen Griffin Dominic finds himself searching for something more in life, he discovers it in the most unimaginable way. Frustrated by unfeeling parents, Griffin is drawn to friend and father figure John, who is teaching him the skill of using a bow and arrow. But will this knowledge be enough to protect him when he is confronted by threatening creatures? And when presented with the challenge of a lifetime, will Griffin have the strength to respond?

Let's look at your criteria one by one:

> **recent,**

Published in 2010.

> **by an author whose last name was (or sounded like) "Lloyd"**

Doesn't match this (unless you have a weird accent!)

> **(and may be female),**

I can't find a first name for the author, but she is female:

[image: author]

> **it was a series of three books**

Book 1: Griffin's Calling. Book 2: Griffin's Temptation. Book 3: Griffin's Legacy.

> **set in an Oregon forest**

Its setting is in Oakridge, Oregon.

> **with a fantastical theme**

They're fantasy novels.

Comment: Most of your Ticks/responses don't actually contain information, it's all in the links. Griffin is also a name, so for all I know this is a coming of age story about a boy named Griffin that lives near the woods.

Comment: You can't make me click!

Comment: @CreationEdge Better now?